# Knockout does not recognize manually click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Here is sample http://jsfiddle.net/HhXGH/57/

I am clicking radio button by jquery but knockout.js does not recognize it.Still it shows first clicked value.

```
<p>Send me spam: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: wantsSpam" /></p>
<div data-bind="visible: wantsSpam">
    Preferred flavor of spam:
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="cherry" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Cherry</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="almond" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Almond</div>
    <div><input type="radio" name="flavorGroup" value="msg" data-bind="checked: spamFlavor" /> Monosodium Glutamate</div>
</div>


var viewModel = {
        wantsSpam: ko.observable(true),
        spamFlavor: ko.observable('cherry')
    };

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

$(':radio:last').click();

alert(viewModel.spamFlavor())
```

Answer (score 4):

This because Knockout is subscribing to the click events of checked radio/checkbox elements only. If you checkout the binding handler code for checked. It does this.

```
var updateHandler = function() {
            var valueToWrite;
            if (element.type == "checkbox") {
                valueToWrite = element.checked;
            } else if ((element.type == "radio") && (element.checked)) {
                valueToWrite = element.value;
            } else {
                return; // "checked" binding only 
                responds to checkboxes and selected radio buttons
            }
```

So in order to get your code to work do this.

```
$(':radio:last').prop('checked', true).click();
```

However if the goal is to check the last value, why not just do

```
viewModel.spamFlavor("msg");
```

This would achieve the same result.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `$(':radio:last').attr('checked', true);` in addition to triggering click makes it work for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/HhXGH/61/

Comment: Yes it works but it is dirty a little so i wonder where is the problem ? Reason of problem is browser, jquery or knockout ?

Answer (score 0):

I have **two different jsFiddles** since I'm not sure exactly what your after.

The **first** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HhXGH/59/) will respond via **alert** when the last radio button is **manually clicked**.

The **second** [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HhXGH/64/) is your posted **/57/** jsFiddle without the alert.

Using an **alert or console.log** with a **function** will actually invoke that function. That said, after you have **manually set** the `.click()` to the last radio button, it's inadvertently reset back to `cherry` since that's the default value.

**RE-EDIT:** The **second** jsFiddle now includes **alert** written in syntax that doesn't invoke the function **& now uses shorted markup**.